# Range.FindNext causing a runtime error 91

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am using VBA to search a 15x15 array for the location (row and column number) of all the '1's and map them to a new location.

```
Sub findvalues()
Dim OldRow As Long
Dim OldColumn As Long

With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:o15")
    Set c = .Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            cellAddress = c.Address
            OldRow = Range(cellAddress).Row
            OldCol = Range(cellAddress).Column
            MsgBox (OldRow)

            With Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16")
                Set oldmapping = .Find(OldRow, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                NewCol = oldmapping.Offset(, 1).Value
                MsgBox (NewCol)
            End With

            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            MsgBox (c.Address)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

The strange thing is, the code runs fine until the fourth loop where it gets to `MsgBox (c.Address)` and throws a

> runtime error 91 - object variable not set

I have a feeling it is down to the `Set c = .FindNext(c)` on the line previous but can't figure out why as it works fine for the first 3 loops.

Comment: Have you tried stepping thru the code using `F8`? That may help. That would tell you exactly which line was the problem instead of you having to guess.

Comment: Yeah. As I said it just gets to the `MsgBox (c.Address)` and throws the error.

Comment: Well then that would mean that `c` is `Nothing` because nothing was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .FindNext derived from,

```
Set c = .Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

... is being superseded by the intermediate,

```
Set oldmapping = .Find(OldRow, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Your .FindNext and loop conditions are no longer valid.

Switch to an alternate method for the second .Find.

```
Option Explicit

Sub findvalues()
    Dim OldRow As Long, OldCol As Long, NewCol As Long
    Dim oldmapping As Variant, c As Range, firstAddress As String, cellAddress As String

    With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:o15")
        Set c = .Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                cellAddress = c.Address
                OldRow = Range(cellAddress).Row
                OldCol = Range(cellAddress).Column
                MsgBox (OldRow)

                oldmapping = Application.Match(OldRow, Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16"), 0)
                If Not IsError(oldmapping) Then
                    NewCol = Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16").Cells(oldmapping).Offset(, 1).Value
                    MsgBox NewCol
                End If

                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                MsgBox (c.Address)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop while (or do while) will still run once when the test is true, here is a simple example:

```
Sub temp()
Dim X As Long
X = 0
Do
    X = X + 1
    Debug.Print X
Loop While X < 5
End Sub
```

Notice 5 shows up in the list of values in your debug window.

A simple test should fix this up for you.

```
If Not c Is Nothing then MsgBox (c.Address)
```

or you could tell it to exit the loop if c is nothing, your choice